# In Functional Programming, is it considered a bad practice to have incomplete pattern matchings

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming

Is it generally considered a bad practice to use non-exhaustive pattern machings in functional languages like Haskell or F#, which means that the cases specified don't cover all possible input cases?

In particular, should I allow code to fail with a `MatchFailureException` etc. or should I always cover all cases and explicitly throw an error if necessary?

Example:

```
let head (x::xs) = x
```

Or

```
let head list = 
    match list with
    | x::xs -> x
    |    _  -> failwith "Applying head to an empty list"
```

F# (unlike Haskell) gives a warning for the first code, since the `[]`-case is not covered, but can I ignore it without breaking functional style conventions for the sake of succinctness? A MatchFailure does state the problem quite well after all ...

Comment: +1, as much as I like functional programming I'm sure there are code smells unique to functional programming that we need to avoid.

Comment: GHC has -fwarn-incomplete-patterns if you want.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with functional programming but, rather, is specific to the style of pattern matching provided in languages derived from the ML family. Many functional languages are incapable of detecting exhaustiveness in pattern matches (e.g. Mathematica).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832992/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you complete your pattern-matchings with a constructor `[]` and not the catch-all `_`, the compiler will have a chance to tell you to look again at the function with a warning the day someone adds a third constructor to lists.

My colleagues and I, working on a large OCaml project (200,000+ lines), force ourselves to avoid partial pattern-matching warnings (even if that means writing `| ... -> assert false` from time to time) and to avoid so-called "[fragile pattern-matchings](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view.php?id=4073)" (pattern matchings written in such a way that the addition of a constructor may not be detected) too. We consider that the maintainability benefits.

Comment: Ah, I haven't thought of fragile matchings - This is indeed a point +1

Comment: Yes, avoiding fragile patterns is really valuable. Dario, you may appreciate the section "Good style" about this in the freely available first chapter of my book OCaml for Scientists (and my subsequent books on F# too): http://ffconsultancy.com/products/ocaml_for_scientists/chapter1.html

Comment: @Complicated see bio i just wanted to give you 16,666

Comment: @CrisStringfellow I like my reputation score to be a multiple of 5, so I downvoted one of your answers that I picked randomly.

Answer (score 9):

Explicit is better than implicit (borrowed from the Zen of Python ;))

It's exactly the same as in a C switch over an `enum`... It's better to write all the cases (with a fall through) rather than just putting a `default`, because the compiler will tell you if you add new elements to the enumeration and you forgot to handle them.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it depends quite a bit on the context.  Are you trying to write robust, easy to debug code, or are you trying to write something simple and succinct?

If I were working on a long term project with multiple developers, I'd put in the assert to give a more useful error message.  I also agree with Pascal's comment that not using a wildcard would be ideal from a software engineering perspective.

If I were working on a smaller scale project on which I was the only developer, I wouldn't think twice about using an incomplete match.  If necessary, you can always check the compiler warnings.

I think it also depends a bit on the types you're matching against.  Realistically, no extra union cases will be added to the list type, so you don't need to worry about fragile matching.  On the other hand, in code that you control and are actively working on, there may well be types which are in flux and have additional union cases added, which means that protecting against fragile matching may be worth it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a special case of a more general question, which is "should you ever create partial functions".  Incomplete pattern matches are only one example of partial functions.

As a rule total functions are preferable.  When you find yourself looking at a function that just has to be partial, ask yourself if you can solve the problem in the type system first.  Sometimes that is more trouble than its worth (e.g. creating a whole type of lists with known lengths just to avoid the "head []" problem).  So its a trade-off.

Or maybe you just asking whether its good practice in partial functions to say things like

```
head [] = error "head: empty list"
```

In which case the answer is YES!

Answer (score 4):

The Haskell prelude (standard functions) contains many partial functions, e.g. head and tail only work on non-empty lists, but don't ask me why.

Comment: +1: I don't understand why you got an uncommented downvote. I said the same thing and got two downvotes...

Comment: Er, what do you expect `head` to do on an empty list? It's not defined, and *should* give an error. In fact in my ghci, `head []` gives "Exception: Prelude.head: empty list", rather than mention a match failure, so the `head` in Prelude *is* presumably checking for empty lists: its pattern matching is exhaustive.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You could have `listToMaybe` as a default instead of `head`. http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe

Comment: I think Haskellers are well aware of this, see for example http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html#id590211 http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_programming_tips#Partial_functions_like_fromJust_and_head , I even remember seeing a proposal to remove such functions from the prelude.

Answer (score 2):

This question has two aspects.

1. For the *user of the API*, failwith... simply throws a System.Exception, which is unspecific (and therefore is sometimes considered a bad practice in itself). On the other hand, the implicitly thrown MatchFailureException can be specifically caught using a type test pattern, and therefore is preferrable.
2. For the *reviewer of the implementation code*, failwith... clearly documents that the implementer has at least given some thought about the possible cases, and therefore is preferrable.

As the two aspects contradict each other, the right answer depends on the circumstances (see also kvb's answer). A solution which is 100% "correct" from any point of view would have to

- deal with every case explicitly,
- throw a specific exception where necessary, and
- clearly document the exception

Example:

```
/// <summary>Gets the first element of the list.</summary>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The list is empty.</exception>
let head list = 
    match list with
    | [] -> invalidArg "list" "The list is empty." 
    | x::xs -> x
```