# head and tail calls on empty list bringing an exception

Tags: ghci, haskell-platform, haskell

I'm following a tutorial. (Real World Haskell)

And I have one beginner question about head and tail called on empty lists: In GHCi it returns exception.

Intuitively I think I would say they both should return an empty list. Could you correct me ? Why not ? (as far as I remember in OzML left or right of an empty list returns nil)

I surely have not yet covered this topic in the tutorial, but isnt it a source of bugs (if providing no arguments)?
I mean if ever passing to a function a list of arguments which may be optionnal, reading them with head may lead to a bug ?

I just know the GHCi behaviour, I don't know what happens when compiled.

Comment: This is actually a special case of a more general problem with "partial functions".  A "total" function will return a result for any arguments.  A partial function is not total; some arguments will return bottom (i.e. an error or an endless loop).  Work on total languages (where all functions are total) is proceeding, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: I don't understand "is proceeding, but don't hold your breath" ?
From what I undertand right now I tend to really prefer total functions over partial ones.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: Don't wait for this languages to become reality ;) For most cases, the `Maybe a` type is the best choice for expressing computations that *may* return values.`

Comment: @Dario maybe I havent understood well... what you mean it's the possibility of return something or not... so two types may be returned (something or void)... I have to wonder about that.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: There are computations that will not always succeed. Returning `undefined` is not a good option since the option of failure is not covered by the type system and the validity of the result cannot be checked (you cannot pattern-match against `undefined`). Whenever there is a computation that can either return a value or fail, one should take `Maybe a`. E.g. `parseNumber :: String -> Int` is a bad choice since it doesn't cover the possibility that parsing fails. `parseNumber :: String -> Maybe Int` states this clearly without the danger of ending up with undefined values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Intuitively I think would say they both should return an empty list. Could you correct me ? Why not ?

Well - `head` is `[a] -> a`. It returns the single, first element; no list.

And when there is no first element like in an empty list? Well what to return? You can't create a value of type `a` from nothing, so all that remains is `undefined` - an error.

---

And `tail`? Tail basically is a list without its first element - i.e. one item shorter than the original one. You can't uphold these laws when there is no first element.

When you take one apple out of a box, you can't have the same box (what happened when `tail [] == []`). The behaviour has to be `undefined` too.

---

This leads to the following conclusion:

> I surely have not yet covered this topic in the tutorial, but isnt it a source of bugs ? I mean if ever passing to a function a list of arguments which may be optionnal, reading them with head may lead to a bug ?

Yes, it is a source of bugs, but because it allows to write flawed code. Code that's basically trying to read a value that doesn't exist. So: *Don't ever use head/tail** - Use pattern matching.

```
sum     [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

The compiler can [guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882334/in-functional-programming-is-it-considered-a-bad-practice-to-have-incomplete-pat) that all possible cases are covered, values are always defined and it's much cleaner to read.

Comment: x:xs yeah that's the way the thing was used in OzML (what I meant by left or right). I am really pleased with this way of writing. thx for the answer.

Comment: I rembember a safe head function with type [a]-> Maybe a

Comment: @Zhen: Yup of course. But handling the `Maybe` is usually not easier than pattern-matching the list as-is, though in some situations `safeHead` might be definitely useful.