# exhaustive patterns

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

I'm learning ML, can somebody please explain what does it mean exhaustive patterns?

Comment: I removed the lisp tag from this question, as I could see no relation to lisp. Lisp doesn't even have pattern matching.

Comment: Some background *why* one should use them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882334

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pattern match is exhaustive if it can not fail. I.e. all cases that could possibly occur are covered by a pattern.

For example the following pattern match is not exhaustive because it doesn't cover the case that the list is empty:

```
fun sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

The following is exhaustive because both cases are covered:

```
fun sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
  | sum [] = 0
```

Generally a pattern match on an algebraic data type is exhaustive if and only if there is a default case or there is a case for all constructors and the match for each sub-pattern is exhaustive.